# Why does the navbar menu flash when using a ng-click on an anchor?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I thought I was being smart when i put:

```
<li><a ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed" href="#/">Home</a></li>
```

as my navigation list items - in order to automatically close the menu (while on a small device).

This worked very well, except that when you are not on a small device, the navigation flashes (reloads).

Does anyone know why? Is there a way around it?

[JSfiddle of the Problem HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/NSsAE/14/) - Re-size the html output window...

Comment: the problem is on bigger screens, the css classes for collapsing are added and so on. (it's acting like collapsing on smaller screens)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's setting height to zero as part of the collapse process, then resetting it with a transition. It's also changing side padding. You may need to incorporate media queries to force height and padding to remain consistent.

Here's a start. There may be a more programmatic way to do it, but it works.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-collapse {
        height: auto !important;
        padding-left: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/NSsAE/16)**

Comment: Thank you, this fixes my issue. However - do you mind clarifying what is setting the height and padding? I assume it's the native behavior of bootstrap? Ty once again.

Comment: Yes, the `collapse` class does that.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved with a little function that checks screen size before reversing isCollapsed value.

**BEFORE**

HTML

```
<div role="navigation" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollaped" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" uib-collapse="isCollapsed">
```

JS

```
$scope.isCollapsed = true;
```

**AFTER**

HTML

```
<div role="navigation" ng-click="collapse()" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" uib-collapse="isCollapsed">
```

JS

```
$scope.isCollapsed = true;

$scope.collapse = function(){
    if(window.innerWidth < 820){
        $scope.isCollapsed = !$scope.isCollapsed;
    }
};
```